PyTorch RuntimeError: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED
I'm trying to perform some inference with YOLOv8 models, simply using the following command:
yolo detect predict source=input.jpg model=yolov8n.pt device=0 
But I'm getting this error related to PyTorch (my pytorch version as shown below is 2.3.0+cu118):
RuntimeError: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=, num_gpus=
I searched a lot, find the CUDAContext.cpp file and fix it, etc but couldn't find a solution.
What is the problem? How to fix it?
Outputs of PyTorch usage and GPU availability as shown below looks good:
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep  2 2021, 17:58:34) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.zeros(2).cuda(0)
tensor([0., 0.], device='cuda:0')
>>> print(torch.__version__)
2.3.0+cu118
>>> print(f"Is CUDA available?: {torch.cuda.is_available()}")
Is CUDA available?: True
>>> print(f"Number of CUDA devices: {torch.cuda.device_count()}")
Number of CUDA devices: 3
>>> device = torch.device('cuda')
>>> print(f"A torch tensor: {torch.rand(5).to(device)}")
A torch tensor: tensor([0.6085, 0.7618, 0.6855, 0.5276, 0.1606], device='cuda:0')

Full stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 306, in _lazy_init
    queued_call()
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 174, in _check_capability
    capability = get_device_capability(d)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 430, in get_device_capability
    prop = get_device_properties(device)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 448, in get_device_properties
    return _get_device_properties(device)  # type: ignore[name-defined]
RuntimeError: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=, num_gpus=

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/conda/bin/yolo", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(entrypoint())
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/cfg/__init__.py", line 583, in entrypoint
    getattr(model, mode)(**overrides)  # default args from model
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 528, in val
    validator(model=self.model)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/validator.py", line 126, in __call__
    device=select_device(self.args.device, self.args.batch),
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/torch_utils.py", line 156, in select_device
    p = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(i)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 444, in get_device_properties
    _lazy_init()  # will define _get_device_properties
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 312, in _lazy_init
    raise DeferredCudaCallError(msg) from e
torch.cuda.DeferredCudaCallError: CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=, num_gpus=

CUDA call was originally invoked at:

  File "/home/conda/bin/yolo", line 5, in <module>
    from ultralytics.cfg import entrypoint
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ultralytics.data.explorer.explorer import Explorer
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/data/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import BaseDataset
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ultralytics/data/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 1478, in <module>
    _C._initExtension(manager_path())
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 238, in <module>
    _lazy_call(_check_capability)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 235, in _lazy_call
    _queued_calls.append((callable, traceback.format_stack()))


This is a known bug in PyTorch which has been fixed in the most recent release

But I already have the latest PyTorch with cu11.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/122815

Hmm it looks merged..Weird. I installed the latest Pytorch. Not sure why I still see it. Maybe I should manually add that line to init.py?

The fix did not entered the 2.3 version. That is probably the reason you are not seeing it. Reference: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/107300#issuecomment-2158900123

This was a bug in PyTorch. To solve, find and go to python3.xx\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py and modify this function:
Remove or comment out this old function:
'''
@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def device_count() -> int:
    r"""Return the number of GPUs available."""
    if not _is_compiled():
    return 0
    # bypass _device_count_nvml() if rocm (not supported)
    nvml_count = -1 if torch.version.hip else _device_count_nvml()
    return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() if nvml_count < 0 else nvml_count
'''

And replace it with this new code:
_cached_device_count: Optional[int] = None

def device_count() -> int:
    r"""Return the number of GPUs available."""
    global _cached_device_count
    if not _is_compiled():
        return 0
    if _cached_device_count is not None:
        return _cached_device_count
    # Check if using ROCm (HIP)
    if torch.version.hip:
        nvml_count = -1  # Assuming ROCm is not supported, set nvml_count to -1
    else:
        nvml_count = _device_count_nvml()  # Use NVML for NVIDIA GPUs
    r = torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() if nvml_count < 0 else nvml_count

    # NB: Do not cache the device count prior to CUDA initialization, because
    # the number of devices can change due to changes to CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
    # setting prior to CUDA initialization.
    if _cached_device_count is None and _initialized:
        _cached_device_count = r
    return r


This answer worked for me when setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES did not

A nicer solution is to call torch.cuda.device_count.cache_clear() after manually setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.
EDIT: what I mean by "manually setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" is calling os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ...

This seems to work before and after setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES with os. But I did not found any docs for the function, only https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.device_count.html#torch.cuda.device_count . Do you know where is defined?

If you click the source button in the documentation, you will see that the function is wrapped in lru_cache. The clear_cache() method is injected buy the lru_cache decorator. The issue itself happens because torch.cuda.device_count() caches the number of visible gpus, which is later changed when setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES manually by os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] in the code. By clearing the cache the function is forced to run again, returning the correct answer.

Just complementing the accepted answer.
This does not seem to be entirely fixed although there is a proposal already merged in pytorch (not in v2.3.1). I am not sure about all of the scenarios, but other scenarios are described in issues #10730 and #126344.
I was having a similar error but with a docker usage and pytorch '2.3.1+cu121' by running a script that sets the gpu internally as in:
docker exec -it container_name python test_gpu.py --gpu_id="1"
I am in a scenario that I can not change the python3.xx\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py file. Also, checking the GPU availability directly was ok (GPU was found with pytorch and I could add a tensor on it such as in the question example) and nvidia-smi was ok too listing all available devices.
From the pytorch issue discussion, this seems to be related to the device caching. One possible solution is to set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES variable before importing torch as suggested in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/126344#issuecomment-2118159363:
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
os.environ["WORLD_SIZE"] = "1"
import torch

But when you also cannot control the imports order (e.g., by using external packages), you can try to set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES when calling the script or command as in:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python test_gpu.py --gpu_id="1"
or with docker:
docker exec -it -e CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 container_name python test_gpu.py --gpu_id="1"

I tried all three solutions above, none works for me, but luckily i find one in csdn, as link stated, just export two variable before the real python run. it works. Like

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2
export CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
nohup python data_train.py > log/log.txt 2>&1 

